# How to foreach through a list and get distinct values from specific columns C#?

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, development, visual-studio, splistitem

I'm able to loop through a list on sharepoint and get the information I need from selected columns, but how would I loop through a list and get only distinct values from a column in C#. For instance lets get all the distinct values from a the email column?

I know I can foreach through the list

```
foreach (SPListItem item in List.getItems(querysp)
{
var itemID = item.ID;
var itemEmail = item["email"];
...

//more vars here

...

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can get Distinct values for email column from your SharePoint list using below mentioned code. i had showed how to insert the distinct email values in drop down list. you can change the code accordingly.

```
try
{
 SPList oList = SPContext.Current.Web.Lists["Your List Nmae Here"];
 SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
 query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Email' /></OrderBy>";
 DataTable dtcamltest = oList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
 DataView dtview = new DataView(dtcamltest);
 DataTable dtdistinct = dtview.ToTable(true, "Email");
 ddl_names.DataSource = dtdistinct; 
 ddl_names.DataTextField = "Email";
 ddl_names.DataValueField = "Email";
 ddl_names.DataBind();                           
}
catch (Exception exe)
{
 Response.Write("Exception at btn_binddropdown_Click :" + exe);
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if it is possible with CAML, but this should work:

```
var emails = List.getItems(querysp).OfType<SPListItem>().Select(item => "" + item["email"]).Distinct();
```

Comment: whenever I post the values from emails into the console. I get the following value `"System.Linq.Enumerable+<DistinctIterator>d__81'1[System.String"` It's posted 5 times (number of items in the list is 5 when it should only be posted 3 times since there are only 3 unique emails) am I doing something wrong?

Comment: You get an IEnumerable back. You could try `ToList()`, even `...Distinct().ToList().ForEach(Console.WriteLine)`