# Get all years of date field in document library programmatically

Tags: document-library, caml

I have a library with lots of documents. Now I need to get all years of the documents for a custom navigation programmatically.

Input:
Many documents in a library that all have a custom ContentType, which has an additional date column.

Desired Output: 
All the years of this custom date column

What I could do is just get all documents and keep the years, but from my understanding this will not perform well. I guess I could do some kind of CAML query, like

```
<GroupBy Collapse="TRUE">
    <FieldRef Name="MyCustomDate" />
</GroupBy>
```

What is certainly missing is that the query should not give me all the dates, but only the distinct years.

I am new to SharePoint and can't find if this is even possible in SharePoint, so it would be great if you could point me in the right direction or try to give me some additional options for this problem!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a calculated column `Year` with formula `=TEXT(MyCustomDate,"yyyy")`.

This will give you year out of your date column. Now you can use this calculated column in caml query or create group by view using this column.

Found this post to get distinct values from SharePoint list column:
http://shlok-sharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/01/select-distinct-or-unique-values-from.html

For you the code will be something like this:

```
SPList objList = web.Lists["List Name"];
SPField field = objList.Fields.GetField("Year"); 
Object[,] values;
uint numberValues = objList.GetDistinctFieldValues(field, out values); 
for (int i = 0; i < numberValues ; i++)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(values.GetValue(0, i).ToString());
   }
```

**Another option** to get distinct values is to use `DataView.ToTable()`.

For e.g.

```
SPList objList = web.Lists["List Name"];
SPQuery query = new SPQuery();
query.Query = "<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='Year' /></OrderBy>";
DataTable dtcamltest = oList.GetItems(query).GetDataTable();
DataView dtview = new DataView(dtcamltest);
DataTable dtdistinct = dtview.ToTable(true, "Year");
```

Comment: I tried this but I get the error that I cannot get the distinct values on a calculated field...

Comment: Then You will need to use DataTable to get distinct values. I have updated my answer. Here is reference: http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/137060/how-to-foreach-through-a-list-and-get-distinct-values-from-specific-columns-c

Comment: Not sure if I understand this in detail, but will this query all the items in the list and therefore will this be a huge performance hit if I have a lot of data in the list?

Comment: Yes this will query all items. And that will result in performance hit for large data.

Comment: Is OOB group by view of document library is lacking somewhere as you choose to go for programatically?

Comment: Yes, we have some very specific requirements... Well we calculated the time required to fetch the years, and it should be ok, even though we may have to cache the result. I will leave the answer open a few days in the hope that I get a faster solution. If I do not get one I will accept this answer

Answer (score 0):

If one is new to SharePoint I don't think Server Side code would be the first approach.

If you have a List View displayed all items are available client side in the `ctx.ListData.Row` object array

You can run this in your own front-end code or in F12 Developer-Tools

```
//Get distinct dates from current View
var years={};
ctx.ListData.Row.forEach(function(item){
    console.log(item);
    var year=String.format('{0:yyyy}',new Date(item.Created));
    years[year]=(years[year]||0)+1;
});
console.info(Object.keys(years).sort());
```

You can replace `.Created` with your own fieldname (note: the Internal field name, not the displayname)